# How do I Check Text Box Input Toast Notification C#

Tags: c#, notifications, windows-10, toast

My Toast Notifications are working fine and I could add some Buttons and check which button was pressed. Now I needed to check for the Input of the Textbox in the Notification, but I don't know how. I searched for something similar on Google, but found nothing.

My Toast Notification looks right, but I can only get the information, which button was pressed.
[image: Here is how it looks like.]

```
protected ToastButton tsen = new ToastButton("reply", "reply") { ImageUri = "Assets/reply.png", TextBoxId = "txtboxrep"};
protected ToastTextBox txtboxrep = new ToastTextBox("txtboxrep");

ToastContent content = new ToastContent()
        {
            Launch = "TextBox",
            Visual = new ToastVisual()
            {
                TitleText = new ToastText() { Text = "Please fill in the gap." },
                BodyTextLine1 = new ToastText() { Text = "I need the following information:" },
                BodyTextLine2 = new ToastText() { Text = txtboxmes }
            },
            Actions = new ToastActionsCustom()
            {
                Inputs = { txtboxrep },
                Buttons = { tsen },
            },
        };

private void TText_Activated(ToastNotification sender, object args)
    {
        //I try to get the text
        var targs = args as ToastActivatedEventArgs;
        ttextreply = targs.Arguments;
        //I only get "reply", this is the buttons name
    }
```

Comment: For people looking at non-UWP/desktop app notifications with user text entry have a look at https://github.com/WindowsNotifications/desktop-toasts   .

Answer (score 1):

You can get the textbox value from the Activated Event in App.xaml.cs like below if you want:

```
protected async override void OnActivated(IActivatedEventArgs e)
{
    base.OnActivated(e);
    try
    {
        if (e.Kind == ActivationKind.ToastNotification)
        {
            ToastNotificationActivatedEventArgs toastArgs = (ToastNotificationActivatedEventArgs)e;
            string value = (string)toastArgs.UserInput["txtboxrep"]);
        }
    }
    catch { }
}
```

Where the UserInput[""] is the name/id of your textbox, and the value of "value" should be set to it.

I have a full example of using Toast for input at the following URL https://comentsys.wordpress.com/2016/05/31/windows-10-universal-windows-platform-toast-input/

Comment: Thx, this is perfect !

Answer (score 0):

To access this you'll need to be using a background task to handle the processing of the input value.
Then you'll be able to access it from [ToastNotificationActionTriggerDetail.UserInput](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/windows.ui.notifications.toastnotificationactiontriggerdetail.userinput)

See an example at https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/tiles_and_toasts/2015/07/08/quickstart-sending-a-local-toast-notification-and-handling-activations-from-it-windows-10/